# Howto upload MultipartFormDataContent which contains a stream using c# in webapi

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Given is the following webapi HttpPost method:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
/// <summary>
/// Eviget controller used for uploading artefacts 
/// Either from teamcity or in case of the misc files
/// </summary>
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadDemoController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] UploadContent input)
    {
        return Ok("upload ok");
    }
}

public class UploadContent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Stream filecontent { get; set; }
}
```

The following code is used to upload a MultipartFormDataContent

```cs
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

StringContent IdStringContent = new StringContent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
form.Add(IdStringContent, "Id");
StringContent NameStringContent = new StringContent($@"foobar");
form.Add(NameStringContent, "Name");

StreamContent TestStream = new StreamContent(GenerateStreamFromString("test content of my stream"));
TestStream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = "filecontent", FileName = "test.txt" };
TestStream.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
form.Add(TestStream, "filecontent");
//set http heder to multipart/form-data
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
try
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("start");
    var response = http.PostAsync("http://localhost:5270/api/UploadDemo/Upload", form).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

By default, the response is **400 (Bad Request).**

With the following controller option, the request is sent to the rest server. This option just says the rest server should ignore null values.

```cs
 builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true)
```

The stream is always null. (Note: The other values are properly set)
[image]

But the stream is actually part of the multipart form data(fiddler output)
[image]

What do i need to do that the Stream is properly mapped in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the data type **Stream**, use **IFormFile**.

So then you can access the properties and the file as follows:

```
var file = input.filecontent // This is the IFormFile file
```

To persist/save the file to disk you can do the following:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
    await file.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: When using IFormFile, i'm able to read the content and everything seems to work. Any Idea why this doesn't work when using Stream?

Comment: If you are using "multipart/form-data" you need to use IFormFile, otherwise, you must use Stream data type.

Comment: Microsoft has documentation around this if you want to stream the file and save memory/disk space rather than buffer the file - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample based on the information from ibarcia.

I've created two webapi controller which allow to read files uploaded as part of a MultipartFormDataContent.

One method defines a parameter which is attributed with [FromForm] and which then contains a property of type IFormFile.
In the second implementation, no parameter is specified and the file can be read
via Request.ReadFormAsync and then accessing the File

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
/// <summary>
/// Eviget controller used for uploading artefacts 
/// Either from teamcity or in case of the misc files
/// </summary>
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class UploadDemoController : ControllerBase
{


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadWithoutParameter()
    {
        IFormCollection formCollection = await this.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        //contains id and name
        foreach (var form in formCollection)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(form.Key);
            System.Console.WriteLine(form.Value);
        }
        foreach (var file in formCollection.Files)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(file.FileName);
            System.Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
        }
        return Ok("upload ok");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] UploadContent input)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(input.Id);
        System.Console.WriteLine(input.Name);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:/temp/neutesttext.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            await input.filecontent.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        return Ok("upload ok");
    }

    public class UploadContent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // public Stream filecontent { get; set; }
        public IFormFile filecontent { get; set; }
    }
}
```